# How to write in twig template view?

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig

PHP code for Drupal 7:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns): ?>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item): ?>
        <?php print $item; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I wrote this, but i'm getting error in Drupal 8. Code:

```
{% foreach row_number, columns in rows %} 
    {% foreach column_number, item in columns %} 
        {{ item }} 
    {% endforeach %} 
{% endforeach %}
```

---

Comment: Please add some more information about the context and what you want to achieve.

Comment: you should read the doc before asking questions

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`for`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html) in twig instead of `foreach`

```
{% for row_number, columns in rows %} 

    {% for column_number, item in columns %} 

        {{ item }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Exception</em>: Object of type Drupal\views\ViewExecutable cannot be printed. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension-&gt;escapeFilter()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">465</em> of <em class="placeholder">core\lib\Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension.php</em>).  getting error after writing for loop

Comment: @user2595130 It looks [like](https://www.drupal.org/node/2031311) you are trying to print an object instead of value, without view the contents of `rows` and `columns` i can't tell you the exact issue, May be some of your objects don't have `__toString()` method

Comment: @user2595130: You could also try to `{{ dump(item) }}` your variable (I'm doing this a lot for debugging purposes) to have a closer look on your variable/object.